# Strange control flow

Tags: c#, control-flow

I'm working on a framework in C# that will depend on pluggable components implemented as classes inheriting a base class. In order to make the components as simple as possible, I am working on some weird control flow.

The base class includes a static method *RunStep(parameter)*. This method is called a number of times by the inheriting class, and each time it is called a condition is checked. If this condition happens to be false, I want the calling method to stop and return. A simplified working version of the code would be:

Base class:

```
class MyBase
{
  private static object RunStep(string parameter)
  {
    if(SomeFunction(parameter))
       return SomeOtherFunction(parameter);
    else
       return null;
  }  
}
```

Inheriting class:

```
class MyInheritor
{
  public void Run()
  {
     object result = RunStep("mystring1");
     if(null != result)
     {
        //perform some logic on result
        result = RunStep("mystring2");
        if(null != result){
            //perform some different logic on result
            RunStep("mystring3");
        }
     }
  }
}
```

What I am wondering is whether it is possible to do something in the base class so that I can simplify the inheriting class to this:

```
class MyInheritor2
{
  public void Run()
  {
     object result = RunStep("mystring1");
     //perform some logic on result
     result = RunStep("mystring2");
     //perform some different logic on result
     result = RunStep("mystring3");
     }
  }
}
```

I would put the parameters in a list and loop over them, but there is logic that needs to happen after each call to the RunStep method, and the logic is different each time. This takes a loop off the table. Also note that the logic between the RunStep calls accesses properties on result, so it crashes without the null checks.

It may seem like a trivial thing, but there may be thousands of these Inheriting classes and  simplifying them is a big deal.

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you are asking for here, but feels like you should take a look at the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: `null != result` A [yoda condition](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions/), this is.

Comment: @tnw: I think, OP just has C++ background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the base class to control the execution flow:

```
class Base
{
    private readonly List<Tuple<string, Action>> steps = new List<Tuple<string, Action>>();

    protected void RegisterStep(string parameter, Action someLogic)
    {
        steps.Add(Tuple.Create(parameter, someLogic));
    }

    protected void Run()
    {
        foreach (var step in steps)
        {
            var result = RunStep(step.Item1);

            if (result == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            // perform some logic
            step.Item2();
        }
    }

    private object RunStep(string parameter)
    {
        // some implementation
        return null;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        RegisterStep("1", () => { });
        RegisterStep("2", () => { });
        RegisterStep("3", () => { });

        // etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to make a function call exit the calling function except for throwing an `Exception`, which you shouldn't do.

What you *can* do to make your code cleaner is to invert the cases.

```
 object result = RunStep("mystring1");
 if (result == null) return;

 result = RunStep("mystring2");
 if (result == null) return;

 result = RunStep("mystring3");
 if (result == null) return;
```

Comment: Thanks, that is cleaner indeed. It still has those pesky null checks that I was trying to get rid of. And yes, I thought about exceptions but they seem inappropriate as I expect this to happen.

Comment: @JoeCapka - There may be a better answer, but not based on what you've shared.  If you're *doing* something with the result, for instance, it'd be very different than if you weren't and could convert it to returning a `bool`.

Comment: `RunStep("mystring1") ?? RunStep("mystring2") ?? RunStep("mystring3")`, perhaps?

Comment: @YoryeNathan - I had that thought, but that's the opposite flow.  It only does Step 2 if step 1 is null.

Comment: Oh true. Sorry about that!

Comment: I am dong stuff with the result. In reality it is a XElement from a web service call and the 'some logic' is fishing out an ID form that XElement to call the next method. Since each web service call has a different result XML, the logic to fish out the ID is different each time.